# Is it possible to determine the original direction of water flow?

Tags: physics

Take two beakers of water and use a spoon to stir water clockwise in one beaker and counterclockwise in the other beaker. Observe the beakers after a sufficiently long time when the water flow has slowed down.

**Is it possible to determine the original direction of water flow after 1 hour? 1 day? 1 week?**

Comment: Is this a legitimate physics question, or more of a lateral-thinking question?

Comment: Yes, it is legitimate physics question, and is a task for a international competition.

Comment: It's not much of a puzzle. It looks to me more like a physics problem. Maybe it should be asked in https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KameliaSavova if it's an ongoing competition, this topic should be close as site's policy doesn't allow this :/

Comment: Is this from an *ongoing* competition? As Flying_whale says, if it's ongoing, we sadly don't allow that.

Comment: Regardless of that, my first answer is no. After you wait sufficiently long, the energy that is maintaining the vortex motion will dissipate and thus the two beakers will be indistinguishable... but of course, something is telling me that the answer is in fact, yes. I'll have to think about that.

Comment: I found this question at https://www.swissynt.ch/images/Problems_for_the_3rd_SYNT_2019.pdf. It's asked in SYNT 2019, which will be held on March 2nd (https://swissynt.ch/index.php/synt/synt-2019). VTC'd.

Comment: The question is not from ongoing competition, it is from IYNT 2019 which will be held in august this year!

Comment: It's common to both competitions, but doesn't make a difference; it's still not allowed.

Comment: From a physics perspective, physicists spend a lot of time isolating a system so they can measure what they are interested in. In a model system, the information would be lost as @hugh says. In practice, it would depend on details. For example, the surface under the breakers might show slight scuff marks which under an electron microscope might show the original direction essentially indefinitely. We would normally assume that the stirring was adiabatic and therefore not enough to do this, but the details would be important